# ContentResolver throws FileNotFoundException on API Level 18

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

When I try to open a file just after inserting it using ContentResolver on Android API Level 18 it throws the exception FileNotFoundException.

If I try to run the same code on API Level 17 it works fine.

```
String fileName = DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();  

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

OutputStream outstream;
try {
    outstream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri);
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outstream);
    outstream.close();

    return uri;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried using [Images.Media.insertImage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) but it didn't work too. Looking source code of this method I realized that code looks much like mine.

Comment: Have you downloaded the Android API Level 18 libraries into your IDE?

Comment: what does the uri look like?

Comment: @BillyBigPotatoes Using SdkManager.exe

Comment: @njzk2 content://media/external/images/media/28

Comment: you have external storage write rights ?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is defined in AndroidManifest.xml. But if error was that the exception would be different, right? It would throw SecurityException.

Comment: shouldn't you pass the file in the `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` value?

Comment: @njzk2 Although the documentation treat this field like "DATA STREAM" I found only examples of its use with file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately using ContentResolver is not working as expected. So I decided to use other approach.

```
try {

    String fileName = DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();  

    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    dir.mkdirs();               

    File file = new File(dir, fileName + ".jpg");               

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

    out.close();

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, 
                   new String[] { file.toString() }, 
                   null, 
                   null);               

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```